# Why do humans circulate monosaccharides instead of disaccharides as in plants?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, physiology, botany, metabolism

Plants transport food mostly in the form of disaccharides like sucrose but humans transport them in the form of a monosaccharide -  glucose.

What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons could be  -

> humans and many other animals have active circulatory systems,
>   there is little need for targeting sugars for specific parts of the
>   body. The entire body would rapidly reach equilibrium with the glucose
>   level of the bloodstream, and thus there likely never evolved the need
>   to target specific organs to receive sugars via disaccharides

Source : [This](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/mole00/mole00218.htm)

Other reason could be that disaccharides are harder to transfer inside the cells than monosaccharides.

Comment: plants are earlier than animals in the phylogenetic tree.  animals later evolved the circulation of monosaccharides I would assume, so there could be an advantage to monosaccharide circulation.  I would look at fungi to see what they do there.